# Global, client-side application state in Relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

What is the current recommendation or best practice for dealing with global application state in a Relay app? I have some state is strictly client-side (e.g. is the navigation panel open or closed) that I need to manage, as well as some RESTful data that isn't available through GraphQL.

I know that Relay 2 may solve this, but waiting "[some time between Date.now() and Date.now() + Infinity](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1369#issuecomment-258842872)" isn't an option ;)

Comment: I don't know if you've heard of Apollo, but it solves this problem by integrating deeply with Redux: http://dev.apollodata.com/

Comment: I have, but the app is nearly done and working fine with Relay, so ripping it out and replacing it with Apollo isn't that appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Add Redux ! The two of them colocates very easily, and this is what is done in the [f8app](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/setup.js).